# OpenSUSE not using all available memory?

Tags: linux, memory, hardware

So I just installed OpenSUSE to use as a local server. I installed 2 sticks of 4gb ddr4 for a total of 8gb. I was messing around, and when I typed free -h I see this:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          5.7Gi       278Mi       5.1Gi        17Mi       370Mi       5.2Gi
Swap:         7.0Gi          0B       7.0Gi
```

The total memory is about 2gb short of what is expected. I find it peculiar that it is only seeing 6gb. It's only using half of one of my sticks? My BIOS correctly reports all 8gb as being present. I'm not really sure how to diagnose what's wrong, I'm newish to linux administration. Any help in finding out how to fix this is appreciated.

Comment: Is your OpenSUSE 32bit or 64bit? Type `uname -a` and check output. Does it say i386 or i686 or X86_64?

Comment: Is it possible that your graphics card uses some RAM? Check in BIOS if some portion of RAM  is dedicated to graphics processor (GPU).